# How to prevent repeated re-soldering of SMD chip during testing?

Tags: soldering, surface-mount, adapter, rework, hot-air

Lets say you have a commercial device you are experimenting with. It has a flash memory chip that cannot be read while in-circuit (I have already tried the clip thing), so you have to de-solder it every time you want to read it, plug it into the socket of the chip programmer, dump the memory, and then re-solder it back onto the PCB, so the device can interact with it.

(I am then doing a diff comparison on the dumps in order to determine how the device's MCU is storing information in the flash chip)

Eventually, after enough heating/cooling cycles, something bad is going to happen to the pads on the PCB. I have ruined a few boards in this way in the past. So I want to minimize the amount of time I am heating it.

I thought "*wouldn't it be great if there were some kind of adapter that I can solder onto the SOIC-8 pad on the PCB, that then connects to an SOIC-8 programming socket, so I can easily remove, read, and reinsert the chip onto the board without soldering*".

But no such thing exists.

So how do most people handle this situation?

[image]

Comment: Why can’t you isolate it from the circuit- at most 6 lines? I can guarantee you just about nobody thinks soldering and desoldering is an acceptable development cycle.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany not sure what you mean by isolate it with 6 lines... I added a pic of the PCB, perhaps you can elaborate?

Comment: _”memory chip that cannot be read while in-circuit”_ Strange design. Find out what’s pulling it down?

Comment: A small castellated PCB that can be soldered in place in stead of the SOIC8 chip, with a SOIC8 socket connected to it trough short leads perhaps?

Comment: @winny from what I have read, it is very common that a flash chip will not allow you to read it in-situ; the adjacent circuitry corrupts the signals. I have absolutely no idea where to start, regarding your suggestion.

Comment: @Unimportant I did find this thing https://sparkoslabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/SOIC-to-DIP-FBFE.jpg, which would be perfect, however I could not find it for sale anywhere

Comment: If you want to know about what is written to flash, why not use a SPI sniffer to catch the writes?

Comment: @bobflux I am comparing two dumps side by side looking for changes. This way it is very easy to get the information I need as I can see exactly what was changed and the memory addresses. I have not used an SPI sniffer, but I would imagine this would be a much more difficult way to do it. But thank you for the suggestion, I will read up on it.

Comment: What is the part number of the memory chip?

Comment: Do you have a schematic or can you trace out each connection to the memory?

Comment: Maybe this socket fits https://www.adafruit.com/product/4726 ; it's for wide SO-8 and your flash looks like it

Comment: @BruceAbbott MX25V1606F

Comment: @winny no schematic. Maybe- its the board in the pic; if I can trace it what would you recommend?

Comment: @bobflux that looks exactly like what I need. Thank you! I will order some of those right away.

Comment: High resolution photos of both sides of the board, mirror the bottom side and print on paper. Then trace every connection from the memory and draw your schematic. bigclive on YouTube shows this method in many of his videos.

Comment: Do some research on that PCB, starting with finding the schematic. You may very well find that something - possibly J17 - is a JTAG connector to permit ISP.

Comment: @user_1818839 Unfortunately it is from a relatively new, and obscure Chinese company who doesn't even have their own website. Searching the numbers on the board yield no results.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany so by "6 lines" I assume you mean because it has 8 pins and one is GND and another is NC, hence 6 remaining?

Comment: @benram14159 one is ground and one is Vcc/Vdd. Maybe it just needs some series resistors so the programmer can overpower the driven outputs.

Comment: @benram14159 Never buy products that lack proper documentation, simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting that re-designing the device to fit some [socket](https://live.staticflickr.com/6143/5942256357_838a6312d1_b.jpg) in it isn't an option for you:

1. You can place a solder jumper (or 0402 0 Ohm) on each trace, which will be manually soldered after "in-circuit" programming. The somewhat controversial solution, a bit easier than IC resoldering
2. You can investigate deeper why you can't run in-circuit programming in the first place.

The second option is preferable because there aren't many factors that might appeal. The most popular one is the too high speed of your flash tool. If the amount of data you need to program isn't too high - take down your flashing speed, and it must work fine.

Also, it's good to design a special mode for the main MCU to leave its pins in a floating state and do not affect the flash tool operation if it might be the case for you (can't see the IC marking on the photo).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually that socket might just work! I would like to learn how to read it without desoldering if possible. I am using the TL866ii, which I'm not sure even has the ability to slow down the read speed. Also I have no control over the MCU in this device.

Comment: If you have no control over the MCU's firmware but can change the PCB layout, you can think of one more option (except the socket) - to implement MCU's supply cut-off. You can prototype it on the current board, and if it works as expected - it might be just a single solder jumper (instead of multiple ones or a socket).